# Need to find first empty field, and update

Tags: t-sql

I am working with a database schema that I cannot change - and I need to run a bulk update. I am moving data between source and target databases, with the same schema. I know this is awful, but it is what I am working with right now.

The schema is as follows:

```
Car
CarType1
CarType2
CarType3
CarType4
```

What I am trying to do - is bring over the CarTypes from my source database, by updating the target CarTypes.

My question is:

If my source record for car "BMW" has 3 CarTypes specified like so:

```
Car: BMW
CarType1: Fast
CarType2: Well Made
CarType3: Good Handling
CarType4: NULL
```

and my target has:

```
Car: BMW
CarType1: Fun Car
CarType2: NULL
CarType3: NULL
CarType4: NULL
```

How would I write an update statement such that CarType1-2-3 from the source would fill in the available NULL fields on the target? So Source:CarType1 -> Target:CarType2. And also - would there be a way to cancel out of the bulk update for this record and log a message if there wasn't room in the target for all of the source fields(say if there's 4 CarType values in my source, and only 3 NULL CarType columns in the corresponding target row?

Thank you!

Comment: is the creation of intermediate and/or temporary tables allowed?  This would never happen in one step.

Comment: Yes, I only need to run this once. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to have a 'hole' in the type columns? For example `Car: BMW, CarType1: Fun Car, CarType2: NULL, CarType3: Good Handling, CarType4: null`

Comment: you know this is not a normalized table? What if you use a temporary table to put the cartypes in, first the ones from the target and second the one from the source. Next step would be to write out the target table and if there remain some entries in the tempTable put them in your log.
don't forget you have a database which loves to store everything in some tables - use it.

Comment: I ended up doing a combination of what everyone suggested. Loaded a temp table with a UNION to get all the unique values, and just run an update to the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about doing it in one statement but four UPDATE statements do the trick.
The final select shows you what columns have overflowed.

```
DECLARE @CarsSource TABLE (Car VARCHAR(32), CarType1 VARCHAR(32), CarType2 VARCHAR(32), CarType3 VARCHAR(32), CarType4 VARCHAR(32))
DECLARE @CarsDestination TABLE (Car VARCHAR(32), CarType1 VARCHAR(32), CarType2 VARCHAR(32), CarType3 VARCHAR(32), CarType4 VARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO @CarsSource VALUES ('BMW', 'Fast', 'Well Made', 'Good Handling', NULL)
INSERT INTO @CarsSource VALUES ('Overflow', 'Fast', 'Well Made', 'Good Handling', 'Overflow')

INSERT INTO @CarsDestination VALUES ('BMW', 'Fun Car', NULL, NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @CarsDestination VALUES ('Overflow', 'Fun Car', NULL, NULL, NULL)

UPDATE  @CarsDestination
SET     CarType1 = s.CarType1
        , CarType2 = s.CarType2
        , CarType3 = s.CarType3
        , CarType4 = s.CarType4
FROM    @CarsDestination d
        INNER JOIN @CarsSource s ON s.Car = d.Car
WHERE   d.Cartype1 IS NULL        

UPDATE  @CarsDestination
SET     CarType2 = s.CarType1
        , CarType3 = s.CarType2
        , CarType4 = s.CarType3
FROM    @CarsDestination d
        INNER JOIN @CarsSource s ON s.Car = d.Car
WHERE   d.Cartype2 IS NULL        

UPDATE  @CarsDestination
SET     CarType3 = s.CarType1
        , CarType4 = s.CarType2
FROM    @CarsDestination d
        INNER JOIN @CarsSource s ON s.Car = d.Car
WHERE   d.Cartype3 IS NULL        

UPDATE  @CarsDestination
SET     CarType4 = s.CarType1        
FROM    @CarsDestination d
        INNER JOIN @CarsSource s ON s.Car = d.Car
WHERE   d.Cartype4 IS NULL        

SELECT  *
FROM    @CarsSource s
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @CarsDestination d ON COALESCE(d.Cartype4, d.Cartype3, d.Cartype2, d.Cartype1) = COALESCE(s.Cartype4, s.Cartype3, s.Cartype2, s.Cartype1)
WHERE   d.Car IS NULL
```